# Too nested loops sql, ran out internal resources

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the following query I try to select a DATES (12 in total),
Within a table but that meets certain restrictions, for this query
I have two boards joined together for one dni:

1.- DATE 1 (date nac = 19-04-2016) searches for a date in the BD between 6 months old and 2 days before the age of 7 months, if this date exists
Put more timely the date = OPPORTUNO: 25-10-2016.
In case you do not find it, look for a date between 6 months old and up to 2 days before the age of 35 months, if this date exists
Put NO OPORTUNO and the date = NO OPORTUNO: 06-05-2017.

2.- DATE 2 looks for a date according to the previous date (OPORTUNO: 25-10-2016)> = 28 DAYS AND <= 32 DAYS, if exists
Put ooportuno and the date = Oportuno: 23-11-2016.
In case you do not find it, look for a date according to the previous date (NOT OPPORTUNE: 06-05-2017)> = 30 DAYS AND <= 929 DAYS, if exists
Put no oprtuno and the date = NO OPPORTUNO: 13-07-2016.

2.- DATE 3 look for a date according to the previous date (OPORTUNO: 23-11-2016)> = 28 DAYS AND <= 32 DAYS, if EXISTS
Put oportuno and the date = OPORTUNO: 25-12-2016.
In case you do not find it, look for a date according to the previous date (NOT OPORTUNO: 13-07-2016)> = 30 DAYS AND <= 929 DAYS, if exists
Put no oprtno and the date = NO OPORTUNO: 10-28-2016.

AND IN SAME WAY THE OTHER DATES UNTIL YOU ARRIVE ON DATE 12.

What I did was to nest DATE 1 on DATE 2 to condition, but date 2 nested on the 3 ..... until the 12th.
I ran until DATE 7 but from DATE 8 shows error: The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. I'll post an example query result.

```
     (CASE   
            WHEN 

            EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )   

                THEN 
                (select concat('OPORTUNO: ',(Select CONVERT( VARCHAR, (SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))))


when

 EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )

then 
(select concat('NO OPORTUNO: ',(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))

                else ''
        END)  AS [FECHA 1 (SF)]
,
 (CASE   
            WHEN 
            EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )   

AND

EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )  
                THEN 
                (select concat('OPORTUNO: ',(Select CONVERT( VARCHAR, (SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))))

when 

EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )

then 
(select concat('NO OPORTUNO: ',(Select CONVERT( VARCHAR,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))))

                else ''
        END)  AS [FECHA 2 (SF)]
,
 (CASE   
            WHEN 
EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )   
and
            EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )   



                THEN 
                (select concat('OPORTUNO: ',(Select CONVERT( VARCHAR, (SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(DD ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 28 AND 32) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))))

when 

EXISTS(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )

then 
(select concat('NO OPORTUNO: ',(Select CONVERT( VARCHAR,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(SELECT top 1  FECHA FROM dbo.z298 WHERE 
                 ((DATEDIFF(day ,(DATEADD(MONTH,5,(SELECT (REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
DEL NIÑO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) FROM dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS where dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI))),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI ),fecha) 
) BETWEEN 30 AND 929) 
and dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS.[NUMERO DEL
DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD 
DEL NIÑO] = dbo.z298.DNI )))))

                else ''
        END)  AS [FECHA 3 (SF)]
```

[Imgage whit the table structure and the result of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtpYa.jpg)

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are trying to do here, but it sounds like you might be able to query a single date from a table, and calculate the other fields from the first query. Can you explain the logic of the query in plain text to better explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give example data and desired results. People shouldn't have to first decipher your convoluted code to work out what you are trying to do and tell you how to do it better.

Comment: Since you asked for suggestions, mine is to start again.  First, write down your objective in the language that you speak.  Then look at your table structure to see where the data is.  Finally, start writing your query.  Take baby steps.  Test early, test often. If  you think you need a loop, you are probably  on the wrong track.

Comment: Have you considered finding the date in a cte or sub query, which you return to find the rest? Or does each value depend on a new return?

Comment: I HAVE ON 12 DATES EACH IN A CASE, WHICH ARE NESTED (DATE 1 IS NESTED ON DATE 2, 2 IS NESTED ON DATE 3 ..... UNTIL DATE 12)
The query WORKS WELL UNTIL DATE 6, WITH DATE 7 SHOW THE ERROR:


The query processor ran out of internal resources and was unable to produce a query plan.

I will post an example query result. I can use some help with ideas, 
I have tried to reduce the code but I can not avoid nesting.

Comment: You should try to describe your task instead of describing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the idea of your algorithm, why you are using overlapping ranges ([28-32], [30-929]) and I'm not sure if this is a good idea to switch all the time from datediffs in month to datediffs in days, but the whole solution might look like this:

```
    SELECT  z.dni,
            z.FECHA,
            CASE 
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, r.dt, z.FECHA) BETWEEN 28 AND 30 THEN 'asdf1'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, r.dt, z.FECHA) BETWEEN 30 AND 929 THEN 'asdf2'
                      ...
            END
    FROM    dbo.z298 z   
            CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT  TOP 1 DATEADD(MONTH, 5, r.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DEL NINO(DD/MM/AAAA)]) dt
                    FROM    dbo.REPORTE_ALTAS_BAJAS r
                    WHERE   r.[NUMERO DEL DOCUMENTO  DE IDENTIDAD DEL NINO] = z.DNI
                            AND r.[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DEL NINO(DD/MM/AAAA)] <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, z.FECHA)
                    ORDER BY dt DESC
                  ) r
```

Perhaps be it must be reverted: `FROM REPORTE... CROSS APPLY (... FROM z298...)`

I'm really not sure if term "nested dates" is applicable to your task. But if it is then you may want to try recoursive CTE instead of making subqueries.